# Solidity on VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, solidity, remix

Why is it that VS code gives me errors in Solidity code whereas the came code is perfectly deployed over remix?

**Screen Shot**

[image: Screen Shot]

Here address[16] shows error.
Whereas this same code is running on remix.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;

contract Adoption {

address[16] public adopters;

function adopt(uint petID) public returns (uint) {
    require(petID >= 0 && petID <= 15);
    adopters[petID] = msg.sender;
    return petID;
    }

function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16]) {
    return adopters;
    }
}
```

Comment: That code won't work on Solidity 0.5.x. You'll need `address[16] memory`. Perhaps whatever extension you're using in VS code is using Solidity 0.5.x and you're using an older version in Remix?

Comment: Hover on the error line and let us know what exactly is the error you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Error cause because you didn't provide `memory` type of storage for return type address[16] like this:
`function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
    return adopters;
    }`

> And for your this question "**Why is it that VS code gives me errors
>   in Solidity code whereas the came code is perfectly deployed over
>   remix?**"
>
> **Answer:** Make sure that you have selected `0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang` or higher compiler version
>   for compile the code in remix ide. If you select this version of
>   compiler, you will get same error as VSCode in remix ide.

Answer (score 0):

In place of `require` in line number 8, put `if`.

also return `true` or `false` instead of PetId. e.g.- if adopter is added in adopter array, return true, else return false.

the right code of adopt function can be this:-

```
function adopt(unit petID) public returns(bool){
      if(petID>=0&&petID<=15){
          adopters[petID]=msg.sender;
          return true;
       }else{
          return false;
       }
   }
```

here, if function return `true`: new adopter in adopters[petID] is added successfully, else `petID` is not between 0-15, which return `false`.